# How to pass variable value from html.html.twig to page-title.html.twig

Tags: theming

Adding a dump '`dd()`' to parent **html.html.twig** template file when rendering a 'page type' page I get, among others, the following pair: `"node_type" => "page"` that I can render within this very template file. When rendering an 'article type' page I get "node_type" => "article". So far so good.

Now I'd need to make use of that variable (node_type) in child template **page-title.html.twig**. Same dump function retrieves some other variable-value pairs but not the node_type one. I guess they're 'local variables' that are not available out of their own scope. However there may be **some way to pass it from parent template** but I couldn't find a straightforward simple solution to it. Any clue?

I'm using latest Drupal 9 stable release, so Twig 2 is in charge of theming.

T.I.A.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass variables between the two templates as such, but you can make `node_type` available in page-title.html.twig by copying the code from [`node_preprocess_html`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_preprocess_html/9.4.x), which is responsible for getting it into html.html.twig in the first place:

```
function MODULEorTHEME_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  if (($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) || ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node_preview'))) {
    if ($node instanceof NodeInterface) {
      $variables['node_type'] = $node->getType();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ty! I'll give it a try. It seems a clean short way to 'pass' the variable to the template.

Comment: Not working. :-(
Variable still not appearing child template page-title.html.twig.
I wonder whether it may have relation to my theme name having capital letters in its name ('MY_subtheme') as it gave me problems before.
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3293623